# How do I get the query string of a URL (the parts after the question mark)?

Tags: php, regex

How can I get only the content from a query string staring from ?:

asegment?param1=value1&param2=value2

NOTE: I only need all the content after the "?", also I want to ommit that character.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a regexp?

Comment: use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query from the current url or just explode on '?'.

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: this does not comes from a uri

Comment: Where does it come from?  It certainly looks like a URI.

Comment: @AndyLester the format it is but if you look it does'nt have schema nor authority, this is just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Regex `\?(.+)`, and a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/13eqyvMAxp). And to use it:

```
preg_match("/\?(.+)/", $inputString, $matches);
if (!$matches) {
    // no matches
}

$result = $matches[1];
```

Comment: i like it but in php throws: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure your string has a query in it, then this will do the trick:

```
echo substr( $string, strpos( $string, '?' ) + 1 );
```

If your string may not contain the query, then check first - `strpos` will return boolean false.

Comment: he wants to omit the question mark also. So it should be strpos+1.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options before that dont require regex like

```
$val = (strpos("?", $url) !== false? substr($url, strpos($url, "?")): "");
```

or parse_url

```
$val = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

EDIT

Fixed condtition where there is not query string

Comment: Where is this `instr()` function defined?

Comment: @nickb my bad s/b strpos... updated post thanks for keeping me honest

Answer (score 1):

\?([a-z0-9A-z&=]+)*

This looks like you're dealing with URLs, consider a library designed for them.  And if you're only interested in getting everything after the ?, then use something like

```
String s = "asegment?param1=value1&param2=value2";
String paramStr = s.substring(s.indexOf('?')-1);
```

Edit: Didn't see that you were using PHP - disregard.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using `strrev` and `strtok`...

```
$url = "asegment?param1=value1&param2=value2";
echo strrev(strtok(strrev($url),'?'));
```

Comment: While this works, it seems a long winded way. Can you comment on the efficiency of this versus (eg) regex or `substr` etc?

Answer (score 0):

You should use $_GET global array `<?php echo $_GET["param1"]; ?>`