# Redirect Query String to Static URL

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am trying to redirect my URL with querystring to URL without querystring, using a wordpress plugin which gets Source and Destination URL

**E.g.,**
From: http://domain.com/page/?do=908    TO:  http://domain/com/page/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the query string of a URL (the parts after the question mark)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593399/how-do-i-get-the-query-string-of-a-url-the-parts-after-the-question-mark)

Comment: Is that even a question? Does it redirect? Does the plugin not work? What errors do you get? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^/page/ /page/? [R=301]
```

the trailing ? removes the query string. Note: I assumed you meant redirecting to domain.com, not domain/com.